# How do I get the text to align with the photo

Tags: css, typography

If you look at the page, http://aurorasvoice.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=37&Itemid=4, you'll see a big table with rows of data containing a photo and a biography. I used valign="top" on the td portion so they could align on the top for each row, but it looks like the photo is a bit higher than the bio. any help? maybe a style setting?

thanks!

Comment: Is this for here or for webmasters?

Comment: ["Please note that if your question is about detailed HTML, JavaScript, or CSS coding, it might be a better fit on Stack Overflow. We prefer questions here about problems or issues that affect entire websites."](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq#questions)  Probably better fit for [SO].

Comment: This question is about table alignment. Wouldn't this be something a designer usually tackles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alignment is actually correct.  HTML line-height includes some spacing above and below the text, otherwise your text would all mash together.  Due to this, your top-pixel of the text won't line up exactly with the top edge of the image.  If you really need it to line-up to the pixels, add a top-margin to the image.

[image]